# Morse functions on subset $\bar \Omega$ of $\mathbb {R}^d$ and its level sets

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $f$ be a $C^{2}(\bar{\Omega})$ Morse function, where $\Omega$ is a bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^d$: this means that
$$
\begin{cases}
f(x) = 0 \\
\nabla f (x) \neq 0 
\end{cases}\text{ on }\partial \Omega
$$
and all the critical points of $f$ in $\Omega$ are non-degenerate. I know that the level sets of such function cover $\bar\Omega$.
  My question is how globally those level sets cover $\bar \Omega$? If someone wants to draw them, how they will look like?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what kind of answer you are looking for here. Are you really interested in global properties, i.e. topological constraints on the level surfaces and their change across critical points? In that case it's probably more useful to post this as a question under topology, and make it more specific. Are you interested specifically in the way the $C^2$ limitation affects local structure? Are you looking for a broad overview of Morse theory in general? Also, why do you tag this as PDE and geometry?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm just looking for a broad overview, specifically the geometric of those level sets. If we take it simply in $\mathbb{R}^2$, how can I draw them? If it is possible, so how about in high dimensions?  For this, I tag geometry. Yes, maybe you are right about PDE tag, but like young research in PDE, I just wanted to have an answer from "a background PDE". The $C^2$  regularity is just necessary to define the Hessian. If there is an answer about the global properties, topological constraints on the level sets and their change across critical points, it will be welcome :).